# Understanding the use of Iterator and Iterable interface

Tags: java, iterator

From my understanding, Iterator enables you to go through elements of a Collection. I can understand its use and advantage for an interface that doesn t natively support a get(index) method, but how about for arrayList or Linkedlist?

As LinkedList (or ArrayList) already let me go through each element( with a for loop for example), why someone would still implement an Iterator? 
Thanks.

Comment: If you want to remove elements from collection, while iterating through it, you would use iterator, not just ordinary for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Iterator` class when iterating a `List` is just one among a lot of ways to iterate lists. For an `ArrayList` it does exactly what you would do with a for loop, iterating with the use of indexes and `get(index)`, just wrapped in the methods of `Iterator` and `ArrayList`. For inheritance reasons `ArrayList` has the functions implemented.